# Get value after a word from plsql string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have employee table in plsql, I have employee id column and emp_email_body column in that, in emp_email_body column i have lengthy values like

```
'blaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahhblaaahh Item: http://google.com bbblahhhhhhhhh'
```

I want to get that url text after the Item: word (Item: word is there in every record and url is after that word)

need to use Regexp but not sure how.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Didnt actually read before putting together a solution, if you need regexp then you already have your answer. If you want just a simple substr then I got this for you:
SUBSTR(:x, INSTR(:x, 'Item: ') + 6)

Comment: that is also working and it is simple to understand..Thank you...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a space after your URL, try something like

```
select regexp_substr(s,'Item:\s+([^ ]+)',1,1,null,1)
FROM t;
```